# How to append records in an existing data file "emp.dat" with two data fields in C++?

Tags: c++, file

What I need to to do: 
I need to append two data fields in an existing data file called "Emp.dat" with two new data fields Ename and Eno. As because I am appending the previous data cannot be deleted.

What I have tried till now :

`Ofstream fout;`
`fout.open("Emp.dat");`

I can open the file in write mode int his way but after that if I am writing something to the file then the previous data is being deleted.

```
char Ename[30]="Biman";
fout<<Ename;
int Eno=5;
fout<<Eno;
```

What am I doing wrong please help.

Comment: .open has other parameters, make sure you are opening in one of the append modes. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/

Comment: So basically if I write `fout.open("Emp.dat", fout::in | fout::ate);` will it open in append mode ?

Comment: It would be faster for you to go and try it, then for you to have written that reply ;P

Comment: got you point and tried it and so it works now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working thanks to @Uberfuzzy

Final code :

```
#include <fstream>
int main () 
{
int eno=12;
char ename[15]="Biman Ghosh";
fstream filestr;
filestr.open ("Emp.dat", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::ate);
filestr<<eno;
filestr<<ename;
filestr.close();
return 0;
}
```

Earlier I didn't know about the other modes that can be used. Now its clear.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read the complete file first and fill a list of structures with the old data. Then write out all of the structures with the new fields